# Load Testing with 250 users

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been testing my web application with a load of 250 simultaneous users. But i am getting a database error -

A Database Error has occured
Unable to connect to the database with the following settings
filename: core/loader.php

I have no idea about the reason the database goes down like this?

Comment: probably you have too many concurrent database connections. check your DB configurations see also [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) (but disregard the outdated PHP-code-examples using the mysql_-functions)

Answer (score 1):

*It sounds like you have hit the MySQL connection limit:*

Add the line below to the bottom of your my.cnf and restart MySQL

```
max_connections = 250
```

You'll need to tweak this value to suit your server best - see [What does max_connections really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686291/what-does-max-connections-really-mean)  and [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) for more details on how to pick this value - but 250 should be fine for your testing

Comment: @sunshine Did this work for you? If it did please select it as the accepted one

Comment: it was a micro instance on AWS and we changed to a medium tier and was resolved